# Increment RGB565 value linearly between point a to b

Tags: c++, rgb

I have an array of 16 cells and I know location 0 (a) and location 15 (b).

I want to increase linearly the RGB value between point a to b.

This is my function so far which gets a hex and converts it to RGB but I am unsure how I can extend it to do the above.

```
void rgb(int hexValue)
{
    unsigned r = (hexValue & 0xF800) >> 11;
    unsigned g = (hexValue & 0x07E0) >> 5;
    unsigned b = hexValue & 0x001F;

    r = (r * 255) / 31;
    g = (g * 255) / 63;
    b = (b * 255) / 31;

    printf("r: %d, g: %d, b: %d\n", r, g, b);
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:
Per my comment bellow this is an example code of trying to solve this..

```
int ra = 0;
int ga = 0;
int ba = 0;

int rb = 255;
int gb = 255;
int bb = 255;

int r = 0;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < W; i++)
{
    r = (ra*((W-1)-i) + rb*i)/(W-1);
    g = (ga*((W-1)-i) + gb*i)/(W-1);
    b = (ga*((W-1)-i) + bb*i)/(W-1);

    printf("loop is: %d -- r: %d, g: %d, b: %d\n", i, r, g, b);
}
```

Is this logic correct? If so, I would then need to get ra,ga,ba and convert them back to hex.

My output is:

```
loop is: 0 -- r: 0, g: 0, b: 0
loop is: 1 -- r: 17, g: 17, b: 17
loop is: 2 -- r: 34, g: 34, b: 34
loop is: 3 -- r: 51, g: 51, b: 51
loop is: 4 -- r: 68, g: 68, b: 68
loop is: 5 -- r: 85, g: 85, b: 85
loop is: 6 -- r: 102, g: 102, b: 102
loop is: 7 -- r: 119, g: 119, b: 119
loop is: 8 -- r: 136, g: 136, b: 136
loop is: 9 -- r: 153, g: 153, b: 153
loop is: 10 -- r: 170, g: 170, b: 170
loop is: 11 -- r: 187, g: 187, b: 187
loop is: 12 -- r: 204, g: 204, b: 204
loop is: 13 -- r: 221, g: 221, b: 221
loop is: 14 -- r: 238, g: 238, b: 238
loop is: 15 -- r: 255, g: 255, b: 255
```

Comment: Integers contain numbers not hexadecimal digits BTW.

Comment: yeah, hex is a way to write a number, not an internal representation, so you can't pass in a "hexvalue",  you just pass in a number which could be turned into any string representation, hex or otherwise.

Comment: When I pass 0xffff (pure white) it prints:
r: 255, g: 255, b: 255
That seems correct or have I missed the point completely?

Comment: Thank you @geza. Would I be right to say that this wouldn't work as I need this to be in RGB565? From what I understand, I need to get the RGB values (which I do from the function above) and then I need to do for each of them a division by 14 (as I know the first and last value). I would then need to convert these new r,g,b values to hex and put it in the following cell and repeat. For example if a is black and b is white: -- see code in original post

Comment: Almost. You still need to divide by 16. Here's the process: extract rgb from the two 565 numbers. Then in a loop of 16, you interpolate the values, and convert them to 565.

Comment: Just did another edit with W-1 instead of using directly W to reflect your comment about 15 instead of 16. Please let me know if that seems correct.

Comment: You current solution is not correct, two reasons: need to divide by W-1, and you ignore fractionals, so in the end, you have imprecise numbers. You can fix that by using my formula, or using fixed point math (i.e., before division, shift the number left by N. And before using the result, shift it back. N could be 8, for example)

Comment: Yeah, now it seems that is correct :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)

I guess the last bit that remains is the conversion from rgb to hex. Is there an easy way to do that instead of reverse engineering my hex to rgb function?

Comment: I think reverse engineering means something else :) but yeah, that's a way. Multiply and divide so it will be in range, then shift it to be in position. (multiply and divide can be replaced with bit operations, for a slightly faster operation)

Comment: @geza Yes you are right, it is just my way of exaggerating things a bit :)

Would it be possible to give me a code snap of that?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yep, I can do it later, now I'm on phone now

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
void rgb(int rgbA, int rgbB) {
    int ra = (rgbA&0xf800)>>11;
    int ga = (rgbA&0x7e0)>>5;
    int ba = rgbA&0x1f;
    int rb = (rgbB&0xf800)>>11;
    int gb = (rgbB&0x7e0)>>5;
    int bb = rgbB&0x1f;

    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
        int r = (ra*(15-i) + rb*i + 7)/15; // + 7 is there to apply rounding
        int g = (ga*(15-i) + gb*i + 7)/15;
        int b = (ba*(15-i) + bb*i + 7)/15;

        int result = r<<11|g<<5|b;

        printf("%04x\n", result);
    }
}
```